# How to use a Mutation Observer to see when a li gets added to a ul

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out what is adding/removing li elements to a ul.  I've tried the following based on code from MDN:

```
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      debugger; 
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      debugger; 
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};


// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[document.getElementsByTagName('ul').length-1].getElementsByTagName('li')[0]; 

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };


// Later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

When I debug my app I see that the targetNode has the correct ul element, but I'm not seeing the li get added in my mutation observer, just various attributes get added to my ul.

I tried changing my targetNode to the following, but I don't hit my mutation observer:

```
const targetNode = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[document.getElementsByTagName('ul').length-1].getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't add any elements to the DOM. It's code for monitoring the DOM for changes.

Comment: See [this tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-dom-breakpoints-with-chrome-devtools-2f60e1fafcb2) for how to set DOM breakpoints in Developer Tools, rather than writing your own monitoring code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm trying to find the code that's adding elements to the DOM, which is why I added this code.

Comment: @Barmar This, but I'm aware of how to set DOM breakpoints in the Developer tools.  I initially tried this approach but hit it so many times I tried writing my own so I could put some additional logic in there.  Developer tools won't let you add conditions to DOM breakpoints, unlike normal breakpoints.  While stepping though my code I was unable to see the li items get added, just see attributes get added to the parent ul object, etc.

Comment: My mistake. Your question is worded such that it wasn't clear. You might try edition your question to say something like "How to Use a Mutation Observer"